# How could one use multi-factor authentication to derive a static secret key?

Tags: passwords, key-management, multi-factor, password-reset

**Scenario:**
The setup is that each user has a randomly generated key `A` used for encrypting data stored on the server and a password-derived key `B` used to store `A` on the server without the server getting access to `A`. So the server stores the ciphertext `C` that is the encryption of `A` with key  `B`. The user recives `C` upon login and can decrypt it with `B` to get `A`, which can then be used to decrypt the other data stored on the server.

This works but if the user forgets the password then all user data stored in encrypted form on the server is lost. It would be great to be able to use some multi-factor setup to derive a different backup key `B'` to derive `A` and reset the password. Ideally there would be a way to do this without risking that the server gains knowledge of `A`.

**Our ideas:**
It would be possible to enforce the use of a client certificate or biometrics to give users a second secret in addition to the password. This is considered too technical for most employees to set up on all of their devices and as such is not ideal.

The users could also be given a physical ID-token but this would be too costly to implement at this time.

A more cost effective alternative to the approach above would be to give each user a password reset key in printed form that they are encouraged to store properly. This option is the best we have come up with at the moment but it has its own set of drawbacks. The users would need to remember where the key is stored and have it easily accessible when needed, it could easily be lost, others could gain knowledge of it if not stored properly, etc.

**Question:**
So the goal would be to, with means other than a password/pin (such as Email, SMS, IP address, authenticator apps, etc) and ideally without means that require trickier user setup (such as client certificates, vpn, biometrics, etc), derive a persistent/static secret key known only by the user and not by any server. How could one do this or why could it not be done?

Comment: The system that you describe is similar to Protonmail's, in that the user uses a single password to both authenticate with the server, and to derive a key (unknown to the server) used for client-side encryption.  See https://proton.me/blog/encrypted-email-authentication for an interesting read on how they implemented this, and see https://proton.me/support/reset-password for how they handle recovery in the case of a forgotten password.

Comment: Thank you, that is a great source of inspiration. They use a recovery phrase with similar function as our proposed solution. It's probably a good idea to use a sequence of random words instead of a sequence of letters if users are expected to write it down by hand. And they also use a recovery file which sounds like an idea that we should look into.